# Find Maximum Value in Array in Ada

Tags: arrays, loops, ada, invariants

I am doing an Ada program with lots of different functions messing with arrays, i got all my sorting functions going, i am now stuck on retrieving the maximum value in an array using a loop invariant to design the loop for that function. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply looping over the whole array?

something like this:

```
function Get_Maximum (Of : My_Array_Type) return Element_Type is
   Maximum : Element_Type := Of (Of'First);
begin
   for I in Of'First + 1 .. Of'Last loop
      if Of (I) > Maximum then
         Maximum := Of (I);
      end if;
   end loop;
   return Maximum;
end Get;
```

will raise an exception if the array is empty, but this is left as an excercise for the reader, if those cases are needed.

Comment: In this case, did you use a loop invariant? i am not sure if i understand the whole concept of invariant.

Comment: I am also getting an error saying i cannot use "Of" as an identifier because it is a reserved word.

Comment: but the loop invariant question still stands... i meant the Max Find Does work, but i still want to know

Comment: Sorry for the reserved word, I just typed without compiler. I don't quite know what you mean by loop invariant, so I can't help you with that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

oenone is correct for an unsorted array, but as you state you have your sorting functions working correctly, why not sort the array, and then use:

```
Maximum := Of(Of'Last);
```

Comment: On a *presorted* array, this is trivial. On an array that is not yet sorted, sorting takes a lot longer than a simple scan through the array.